# "Backups" app missing after Ubuntu 22.04 Minimal install. How to install it now?

Tags: dual-boot, software-installation, 22.04, backup, reinstall

I did a Minimal install of Windows 10 followed by Ubuntu 22.04 a week or two ago. Now discovering "Backups" isn't listed in my Ubuntu Apps -- yes, even in the utilities folder.

I've looked here for a fix and even tried some command line things but can't find the "Backups" app to install it.

Appreciation in advance for your assistance.

Comment: It's not in my install of Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: From a USB disk created from the Ubuntu site instructions.

Comment: Your comment gave me the idea to look to see if it is in my USB install disk. And Backups is there when I boot that up in the Try Ubuntu mode. But it wasn't installed onto my laptop HD. Only in the USB disk. Could I just install "Backups" somehow?

Comment: Did you happen to use the minimal installation option? That *might* cause this.

Comment: I did use the minimal installation option. Perhaps that is why it did not get installed.

Comment: Edited the title and question to clarify up front that this was a minimal install. That's critical information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Backup app package is named *deja-dup*. Déjà Dup is a simple backup tool. It hides the complexity of backing up the right way (encrypted, offsite, and regular) and uses duplicity as the backend.

To install Backup in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install deja-dup
```

or

```
sudo snap install deja-dup --classic
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll do this instead of Backups. Thanks everyone for the help. I thought it would be easy to find and install Backups but I learn things all the time.

Comment: I see the package installed is Backups. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your Ubuntu Software application.

[image]

It's called "Backups". The actual package name is `deja-dup`, you can also search for that.

[image]

Comment: It's not in my Ubuntu Software app.